# Gradle build fails for dependency of avro-tools

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I've been trying to convert a maven project into a grade build.
One of the dependencies in the POM.xml is for avro-tools, as follows :

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
<artifactId>avro-tools</artifactId>
<version>1.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

On running gradle init in the project gradle generates a build.gradle file from the pom.xml with the following as a dependency :
implementation group: 'org.apache.avro', name: 'avro-tools', version:'1.10.0'

However, on running the build, I get the following error :

```
   Could not find avro-mapred-1.10.2-hadoop2.jar (org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.10.2).
    Searched in the following locations:
        https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro-mapred/1.10.2/avro-mapred-1.10.2-hadoop2.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

If the same build is run in maven, the build works fine.

Edit :

Full build.gradle file :

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}



dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version:'2.12.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version:'2.4.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-yarn_2.12', version:'2.4.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-sql_2.12', version:'2.4.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-hive_2.12', version:'2.4.1'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-avro_2.12', version:'2.4.1'
    implementation group: 'com.typesafe', name: 'config', version:'1.4.1'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version:'1.5.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.avro', name: 'avro-tools', version:'1.10.2'
    implementation group: 'com.typesafe.play', name: 'play-json_2.12', version:'2.9.2'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.12'
    testImplementation group: 'org.scalatest', name: 'scalatest_2.12', version:'3.0.5'
    testImplementation group: 'org.specs2', name: 'specs2-core_2.12', version:'4.2.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.specs2', name: 'specs2-junit_2.12', version:'4.2.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.scalatestplus', name: 'mockito-3-4_2.12', version:'3.2.4.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version:'3.4.2'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version:'4.0.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Edit : Figured out the problem, it wasn't avro-tools alone but avro tools & the spark-core 2.12 plugin which was causing the dependency conflict.
avro-tools 10.2 references avro-mapred 1.10.2 as a transitive dependency while spark-core 2.12 references avro-mapred 1.8.2 as a dependency.
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: `avro-mapred` is not the same as `avro-tools`. Make sure you have correct goupId and artifactId defined in the build script. The `implementation group: 'org.apache.avro', name: 'avro-tools', version: '1.10.2'` from your Maven snipped works fine for me in Gradle.

Comment: @Andrey I've added my full build file in the answer. I am using intellij IDEA & the gradle version is 7.1. The problem still persists

Answer (score -1):

Though I faced issues with a different library IMO root cause for both could be the same.

Excluding the transitive avro-mapred dependency from Spark_*_2.12 did the magic for me. Now I am to execute the Gradle build which was failing earlier with:

> Could not find avro-mapred-1.11.0-hadoop2.jar (org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:1.11.0).

But still not clear why Gradle behaved in a weird way by looking for a different version altogether appending -hadoop2 to version.